# Cannot dynamic cast to ptr

Tags: c++, templates

I am trying to implement very basic class similar to boost::any, but there is a problem I am facing with and I cannot overpass this. Problem is with casting pointer to another using dynamic_cast with error saying:

`cannot dynamic_cast 'input.Any::m_targetPtr' (of type 'class Any::StorageInterface*') to type 'int*' (target is not pointer or reference to class)`

source of class is as follows:

```
class Any{
public:
    template <typename T>
    Any(T input): m_targetPtr(new StorageImpl<T>(input)){}
    ~Any(){delete m_targetPtr;}

    class StorageInterface{
    public:
        virtual ~StorageInterface(){}
    };

    template<typename T>
    T* cast(Any& input){
        return dynamic_cast<T*>(input.m_targetPtr); //here comes the trouble
    }

    template <typename T>
    class StorageImpl : public StorageInterface{
    public:
        StorageImpl(T& input): m_target(&input){}
        T* m_target;
    };

    StorageInterface* m_targetPtr;
};
```

and this is how I want to execute this:

```
int i=150;
Any asdf(i);
cout<< (asdf.cast<int>(asdf)) << endl;
```

So my understanding is. I have an `int` variable and to the `cast` template I pass pointer to this int and `T` in template is int, therefore in the cast source we have `int` as deduced parameter `int*` as returning value and I execute `dynamic_cast<int*>` with argument `m_target` of type `StorageInterface*`. Why then I am getting an error, that my target is not a pointer?

Comment: Have look at [the six things dynamic_cast can do](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/dynamic_cast) and tell us which of these you are trying to do.

Comment: Yes thanks, it's due I tried lots of different options with this method and I forgot to restore it to the previous state.

Comment: Isn't it that in order to `dynamic_cast` the argument must be a poly-morphic type?

Comment: If expression is a pointer or reference to a polymorphic type Base, and new_type is a pointer or reference to the type Derived a run-time check is performed this is what I was trying to do. So I guess then, that I cannot cast to int as int is basic type?

Comment: @DawidPi You could if the other type was derived from `int`. It's not at all clear to me what you're expecting `dynamic_cast` to do. If the types aren't related, what are you expecting to happen exactly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see the following problems in the following code.

```
template<typename T>
T* cast(Any input){
    return dynamic_cast<T*>(input.m_targetPtr); //here comes the trouble
}
```

1. You need to cast to `StorageImpl<T>*`, not `T*`.
2. `StorageImpl` doesn't expose its member, `m_target`.

Expose the `m_target` member, by making it `public` or providing a function that returns the value.

Change the `cast` function to:

```
template<typename T>
T* cast(Any input){
    return dynamic_cast<StorageImpl<T>*>(input.m_targetPtr)->m_target;
}
```

**Suggestion for improvement:**

You don't need the `input` argument in `cast`. It can be:

```
template<typename T>
T* cast(){
    return dynamic_cast<StorageImpl<T>*>(m_targetPtr)->m_target;
}
```

Then, your call can also be simplified to:

```
cout<< (asdf.cast<int>()) << endl;
                  //  ^^^ No need to use asdf again in the call.
```

**Suggestions for further improvement**

The `StorageImpl` in your posted code stores a pointer to an object that can easily become invalid. I would recommend storing an object instead. Then, `Any::cast()` can return a reference instead of a pointer.

```
class Any {
   public:
      template <typename T>
         Any(T input): m_targetPtr(new StorageImpl<T>(input)){}
      ~Any(){delete m_targetPtr;}

      class StorageInterface {
         public:
            virtual ~StorageInterface(){}
      };

      template<typename T>
         T const& cast() const {
            return dynamic_cast<StorageImpl<T>*>(m_targetPtr)->m_target;
         }

      template<typename T>
         T& cast() {
            return dynamic_cast<StorageImpl<T>*>(m_targetPtr)->m_target;
         }

      template <typename T>
         class StorageImpl : public StorageInterface {
            public:
               StorageImpl(T const& input): m_target(input){}
               T m_target;
         };

      StorageInterface* m_targetPtr;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that `dynamic_cast<T>(X)` cannot convert type X to type `T` if `X` doesn't belong in the same class hierarchy as `T`. Dynamic cast is meant for polymorphism, for down-casting `Animal*` to `Dog*`, for example, where `class Dog` inherits from `class Animal` and `class Animal` contains a virtual function. The problem is that `int` is not a class type, so `dynamic_cast` can conclude early that `int` and `StorageInterface` don't share a class heirarchy.

The error message is not saying that your target is not a pointer, it's saying that your target is not a pointer to a class object (and isn't a reference to a class object either).

R Sahu makes the point that you meant to cast to `StorageImpl<T>*`, which makes a lot more sense.

Answer (score 1):

`dynamic_cast<T>` is intended to use to convert a pointer to a polymorphic struct to another polymorphic struct in the same hierarchy. A polymorphic struct is a struct with at least one virtual function or virtual inheritance. Clearly, int* is not a struct and is not polymorphic.

You probably meant to make this cast instead:

```
template<typename T>
T* cast(Any input){
    return dynamic_cast<StorageImpl<T>*>(input.m_targetPtr)->m_target; // better?
}
```

And why sending a copy of the object to itself? I would be less error-prone to limit the function to the instance itself:

```
template<typename T>    
T* cast(){
    return dynamic_cast<StorageImpl<T>*>(m_targetPtr)->m_target; // even better
}
```

You can use it like this now:

```
asdf.cast<int>();
```

Finally, to make your code even cleaner and less error prone, one last thing could be done. Did you see the potential undefined behaviour? You have a double deletion in you code:

```
template<typename T>
T* cast(Any input){
    return dynamic_cast<T*>(input.m_targetPtr); //here comes the trouble
    // input is deleted here, so asdf will have a dangling pointer and double delete the m_targetPtr!
}
```

And in your constructor, you save the address of a temporary:

```
// input is a reference to a variable from the 'Any' class constructor, it will be deleted
StorageImpl(T& input): m_target(&input){}
```

Passing by value (and move) could fix this.

Any code using this class is subject to these error. Using a `std::unique_ptr` and value semantics will do the trick:

```
struct Any {
    template <typename T>
    Any(T input): m_targetPtr(new StorageImpl<T>(std::move(input))){}
    /* ~Any(){delete m_targetPtr;} */
    // no destructor needed here, you can safely remove the line above.

    // you could implement a copy constructor which clone the m_targetPtr.

    class StorageInterface{
    public:
        virtual ~StorageInterface(){}
    };

    template<typename T>
    T& cast(){
        return dynamic_cast<StorageImpl<T>*>(m_targetPtr.get())->m_target;
    }


    template <typename T>
    class StorageImpl : public StorageInterface{
    public:
        StorageImpl(T input): m_target(std::move(input)){}
        T m_target;
    };

private:
    std::unique_ptr<StorageInterface> m_targetPtr;
};
```

This code will require T to be moveable.

Comment: Thanks. I was aware of the problem with pointers, however I wanted it to compile at least then take care of it. But thank You either way

Comment: very glad to help you! :)